# how is once load js file to original page for .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .load() call doesn't execute javascript in loaded html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file)

on the page loading with .load(),  can not be using jQuery?
do will re-load files js to page loading with .load()?
How can load once js file in page header?
This is content page that is loaded with .load()

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/js/ok.js"></script>
// not want this js files (jquery-1.6.min.js - ok.js) load  here 
//i once they to page original load, with this load is twice load
<div class="insert">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table class="servicesT" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="servHd">
                   hello
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" title="name">
                </td>
                <td class="servBodL">
                </td>
                <td class="servBodL">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are asking - can you try to rephrase the question?

Comment: `<script>` tags inside content you get with  `.load()` are ignored: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429927/jquery-loading-a-page-with-load-and-selector-doesnt-execute-s

Comment: @Felix, the filtering to scripts happens only if there is a selector passed as well.. otherwise the entire page is inserted..

Comment: @Gaby: Oh ok... (should have read more carefully)...

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you meant this:

$("#someDiv").load("sompage.html .insert")

should load someDiv with the content of the div with class insert.
An ID would possibly be better and I do not know if the scripts are loaded, firebug would see if they were