# Jquery/Ajax executing php without .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I understand that you if you use Ajax's .load() that it strips any scripts (including PHP) so they won't run if you're loading content into a div.  Is there a way around this?
I "think" this might be part of the solution but, honestly, I don't know what to do with it >> [Jquery - Loading a page with .load and selector doesn't execute script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429927/jquery-loading-a-page-with-load-and-selector-doesnt-execute-script)

Basically, here's what I have:
On one page, I have some PHP that does something similar to:

```
    <?php
    ... perform some "while" loop ...
    ... set some variables ...
    echo "<div id='info' class='businfo'>";
    echo "something something $some_variable something something";
    echo "</div>
    ?>
```

On the second page, I want to retrieve the contents of "" and display it in another div.  From what I'm reading, I think there may be workarounds but I haven't seen one that's easy enough for me to work worth :(

Anyone have a simple solution with sample code?

Thanks in advance,

- d -

Comment: You can pass variables with your ajax, which you'd then process on the page being called, generate your page, which is then loaded into your div or whatever you're using. You can't execute PHP on the page that called the load. PHP is server side only. Think of ajax as an invisible browser being used by a computer. It reads the page the same way as your web browser would.

Comment: First, thanks for the info about passing variables.  How can I pass the first page to the second?  If "might" be able to manipulate a work around. 
Secondly, about executing the PHP, I thought there was someway that the entire page could be held in some other environment or such, executed and then passed back to the div..but I'm not sure. :/

Comment: I usually use post: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ - see the examples near the bottom.

Comment: Here's an example process: Page 1 loads. A button is clicked - some ajax calls page 2, with some POST data. Page 2 processes that POST data (like if you submitted a form), and renders the output. Ajax then returns this rendered output of Page 2 to Page 1, and then Page 1 does something with that data, such as putting it in a div.

Comment: ahh..I see.  Unfortunately that won't work in my case.  The second page really isn't going to get seen by others as it's really just a container for other info.  Thanks for the help though.  The variable passing is good info.